# Single Phase (L1&L2) in 3 Phase Supply Calculation

Tags: three-phase, single-phase

I have multiple single-phase loads required to be powered from a 3 phase supply with neutral (208/120) V. I'm going to tap to (L1, L2) & (L2, L3) and (L1,L3) respectively. Assuming the load was 1400 W, rated input 100-240 V AC, how can I calculate the current for each phase?
Since later extra single phase L-N to be added into the system too. But first I have to understand how single phase (L-L) current distributed.

For starting example with 6 loads connected 2 units-(L1-L2), 2 units-(L1-L3), 2 units-(L1-L3)
1400 W X 2 units = 2800 W
I = P/(VLine X PF)  considering PF= 1 just to ease understanding
I = P/(VLine)
I = 2800 W/208 V = 13.46 A
13.46 A is current calculate for L1 and 13.46 A L2 or 13.46 A is both L1&L2.

If 13.46 A is load for each 2 loads in parallel.
then 13.46 A + 13.46 A = 26.92 A for L1,
26.92 A for L2,
26.92 A for L3.

Is it correct?

I'm not really clear about this 13.46 A. Kindly advise.

[image: SinglePhase2hot]

Comment: HI greybeard, thanks for the answer, do means like this.
1400W X 6 = 8400w total power
then 8400W / 3 /208V = 13.46A > current for each phase?

Comment: No. 208 V is line-to-line voltage, I think of ("unqualified") *line voltage* as line-to-neutral - pick \$208/\sqrt 3\$ or 120.

Comment: 120V is phase voltage (line to neutral) where from usual term.
this what you meant?
8400W/3/120V = 23.33A it will be the same as
8400W/√3/208 = 23.33A. 

hmmm i think 23.33A will be the answer if load was connected phase to neutral. but if connected phase to phase as per diagram, is it 13.46A per phase ? or how.

Comment: According to en.wikipedia, you are right about the use of *line voltage*. (*Phase voltage* may differ.) Usage is different enough in my first language - that would be "triangle voltage" as oppose to "outer conductor", "star" (wye), "grid" or just unqualified "tension"/ *voltage*. Line-to-line has *line current* to mean something different from *current in a load operated at line voltage* - sheesh.

Comment: All bets are off with reactive loads (without further specification). With a symmetrical resistive load (you assumed PF=1), just divide one third of total power by line-to-neutral voltage - at any given power, the current won't change whether the load is delta- or wye connected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Three pairs of 1400 VA units may be either delta- or star-connected.

When delta-connected the input voltage to the units would be 208 V.

[image]

The current drawn by a pair at 208 V would be 2800 / 208 = 13.47 A and the resulting line current 13.47 x √3 = 23.33 A.

When star-connected the input voltage to the units would be 120 V.

[image]

The current drawn by a pair at 120 V would be 2800 / 120 = 23.33 A and the same would be the line current as well.

With the loads being balanced, no neutral connection would be required.

Comment: Hi vu2nan. thanks a lot for this wonderful explanation and diagram. now it was clearer to me about equivalent delta. it was the way load connected making it delta.  The resulting line current is 23.33A which obtain by 13.47A X √3 = 23.33A. At first i thought i can have the resultant line current by adding both L1+L2. That's why 26.92A. 

this resultant line current will be same? time √3 even it if i dont have balance load?
ill popup with other question later since im planning to have combination of single phase load, 120V, 208V and 3 phase load. 

thanks again for you time and patience.

Comment: Anytime, Epe! With a balanced three-phase load and zero neutral current, the neutral need not be connected. With a load imbalance, not connecting the neutral would result in unequal voltages across the loads.

Answer (score -1):

That is not correct. What you are describing is equivalent to a delta-connected balanced 3 phase load.

26.92A would be your phase current. You are interested in the line current.

To calculate your line current, you must multiply your phase current by the square root of 3.

Comment: Hi Pat, thanks for your answer! Sorry im not getting what do you means 
 by "describing is equivalent to a delta-connected balanced 3 phase load."

it was wye/star, where I can have 120V single phase and 208V 3phase and 208V single phase. From my understanding in star connection, I phase=I line.

and for this single phase (L to L), does it work like single phase + neutral. Current at L = Current at N?

Comment: Hi Pat, That's not correct either. The phase current would be 13.47 A and the line current 13.47 x √3 = 23.33 A.

Comment: Vu2nan, the question is not consistent. Epe asks “If 13.46 A is load for each 2 loads in parallel…” which suggests a total phase current of 26.92A. They proceed to calculate this same result, but mistakenly represent it as a line current and ask if it is correct. I indicated that is not correct, and explained the relationship between line and phase current on a delta-connected balanced 3 phase load.

Comment: Hi Pat, In any case, your statement '26.92A would be your phase current.' is incorrect.

Comment: If you have 2 loads connected in parallel across each phase, with each load drawing 13.46A, then your phase current would be 26.92A per phase. In his first example with 1400W loads, then yes, the phase current would be 13.46A.

Comment: sorry pat, my word quite confusing, 2 load connected in parallel means (1400W+1400W) =2800W. both load drawing 13.46A as 2800W/208 =13.46A. One load should be half of it which is 1400W/208V = 6.73A

while "13.46 A + 13.46 A = 26.92 A for L1" is simply my wrong assumption since i dont know where to begin to find the line to line current. after looking at vu2nan diagram it was getting clearer but on equivalent delta connected.

Comment: 26.92A should be ignore. it was not correct at all and misleading calculation and info.
now it was clear that 13.47A was the phase current (sum of current through the 2 parallel load)